# Terminal emulator with tiling mode

Tags: linux, open-source, terminal-emulator

I'm Ubuntu user and now I'm using standard GNOME Terminal. Sometimes I'm configuring servers and I need to focus on several terminal windows. With GNOME Terminal I have to do switch between tabs all time, this isn't comfortable.

What terminal have tiling mode? I mean ability to split one terminal window to several (see screenshot)
[image]

(This is i3 tile manager, but I need just terminal emulator, not window manager)

Comment: You're looking for split screen feature. I've used [Deepin Terminal](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/12/deepin-terminal-updated-to-latest.html) (in Deepin Linux, a variant of Ubuntu) and it meets the criteria here. IDK which Ubuntu version you're running so you might need to search on Google.

Comment: I'm currently using [Konsole](https://konsole.kde.org/) which also has split-screen feature. Konsole is part of KDE so you might need to install core libraries or something to get it work. Things are usually straightforward for installing in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Terminator is your answer here :) https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html (source code at https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator)

You just right click or use the menu bar to create a near-infinite number of split-screens. It's normally in the repos, so can be installed via `sudo aptitude install terminator` on Ubuntu/Debian or `sudo dnf install terminator` on Fedora/CentOS.

Answer (score 5):

All terminals have the ability to split the screen into tiles. You just have to run [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux).

In Screen, press `C-a S` (that's a capital `S`) to split the screen into [regions](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Regions). The second region is created below the current one. A popular patch (not available in the antique official release, but included in many distributions and in the source repository) allows a vertical split with `C-a |`. To run a command in the new region, create a [new window](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Screen-Command) with `C-a c`. Use `C-a TAB` to cycle between regions.

In [Tmux](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1), use `C-b "` to split the current pane into two horizontally, or `C-b %` for a vertical split. A shell is automatically started in the new pane. Use `C-b ARROW_KEY` to navigate between panes.

Comment: [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) is the way to go.   You don't have to get used to a new terminal program - it even works on tty screens (`Ctrl` `Alt` `#`) - it is modern, supported by all major distros and simple to use.

Comment: Downside of tmux or screen is mouse don't working :C

Comment: @gephaest Yes they do. If you want mouse clicks to change panes: screen: `defmousetrack on`; tmux: `setw -g mode-mouse on`. If you want mouse events to go to the application, all you need is to convince it that the terminal supports mouse events (which is not the case for `screen` by default). If you need help with that, ask on [unix.se].

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've already found your answer, if not have a look at Tilix, an amazing terminal app with both tiling and tabs combined: https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix